# Display New item Icon with SPServices

Tags: javascript, spservices, item

I want to display the New Item Icon with SPServices or using custom Javascript to show a new item icon for n days when Created. I achieved this using XSL. Thank's to Mark Anderson(http://sympmarc.com/2008/08/05/new-item-icon/).

But I need the same for SPService. Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

SPServices really has little to do with this. You can retrieve information about items using GetListItems, but the decision whether to show a new item icon rests with you on the client side. You can really choose to show it for just about anything.